# Add message attributes from lambda back to SQS DLQ

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, triggers, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda trigger on an SQS queue which is configured with a DLQ.

When my lambda failed the original message from the queue will be redirected to the DLQ.
Now I want to add more information to this original message (like why there was an error etc). I know that I can't modify the original message but I saw that a message can have additional message attributes `RequestID, ErrorCode, ErrorMessage`.

How can I use/ setup them from my lambda function (NodeJS) ?

Comment: How you pass message to DLQ from NodeJs Code or AWS DLQ settings?

Comment: I have a lambda trigger listening to the DLQ. And the message are sent to the DLQ with SQS redrive policies.

Comment: okay. In this case AWS automatically adds the attributes so you can debug why it is not processed. You can check the message from logs and cross check in cloudwatch.

Comment: When I check the DLQ I can see the message body of the original message, but in the message attribute tab, the fields are empty. I am throwing the error like this in the lambda function : `throw new Error((err.message) ? err.message : JSON.stringify(err))`. Is there a way to specify the attributes manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Although lambda does not let you edit retried messages in any way before they get sent to DLQ, we can **indirectly** add a few `attributes` like below to the message that can explain why it failed.

[image]

This only works for specific cases, mainly for `asynchronous, non-stream-based invocations` which basically means lambda’s native async retries or `SNS` triggers work but `SQS` based retries, for instance, don’t. The other condition is that the exception returned/thrown must be an Error or an extension of the Error prototype for node lambdas.

Something like

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, cb) => {
   class CustomError extends Error {
       constructor(message) {
           super(message);
           this.name = "Some Lambda Error";
           this.message = message;
       }
   };
   let error = new CustomError("Something went wrong")
   cb(error);

   // or just simply

   cb(new Error("Something went wrong"));
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to perform same trick for Lambda written in Python?

Comment: I haven't tested that. But I think it should work with python functions too.

Comment: This is great, but I would like to know how to do this in serverless if possible?